# Gradle project depends on Depending Gradle Projects jar

Tags: gradle

Guys Im new to Gradle and need you help in solving a problem.
I have a project Structure like this :

root
  |
  |- P1
    |--- P2
         |--- P2.1
         |--- P2.2
         |--- P2.3

P1 is depending on P2
 
P2 is deepening on P2.1 - P2.3

I'd want the P1 to include subset of the P2's depends such as P2.1 and P2.3 in its class path. Currently the build.gradle of P1 contains

```
dependencies {
  compile P2:4.15.0-SNAPSHOT
  compile P2.1:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT
  compile P2.3:5.1.0-SNAPSHOT
}
```

Ideally P1 should use the identical versions of what P2 is using for both P2.1 and P2.3. 
Is there a way i can get the versions automatically from the P2 without having to change them manually each time a version on depending module changes ?
Thank you.

Comment: You should have the dependencies of P2 automatically available in P1 (without mentioning them explicitly).

Comment: Your structure implies that P2 is subproject of P1 and P2.x are subprojects of P2. You defined P1 dependency on P2.x. It doesn't make sense to me, shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: P1 is an extended version of P2. Therefor P1 has dependency to P2. So if any implementation is based by P1 it should be something which P2 depends on. That is why P1 has dependency for both P2 and its dependence P2.1 etc.. . The reason to make it automated it that if P2 upgraded with new versions of its dependents,  P1 should also changed with respective versions.